# Javascript - simply get height of an element

Tags: javascript, css

I know this properbly is a duplicate, but i cant get it right from some of the other answers!
Really hope you can help!

I simply want to get the width of an element, and then assign it to the height of the same element.

But i cant seem to get the width passed... 
And I really dont know why - just gets and "undefined".

Read something about the js asking for the width before the elements are added to the DOM, but no matter where I place my "onload", og place the js script, it doesnt seem to make any difference, and i still can add static height to the same element, but just cant get the width! Thanks!

```
var width_ele = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
var width = width_ele[0].style.offsetWidth;

alert(width);

var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
ele[i].style.height = 100 + "px"; // here I wanted the "100" to be the variable "width"...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qL0hj4jc/10/

Comment: Share your code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated your code.

You need to use

```
var width = width_ele[0].offsetWidth;
```

Here is the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qL0hj4jc/4/

You should use the .offsetWidth and .offsetHeight properties. Note they belong to the element, not .style.

Comment: Great it worked for you :) You can mark the answer as selected for future reference

Answer (score 4):

```
var width = width_ele[0].offsetHeight; // did you mean offsetWidth?
```

`offsetHeight`/`offsetWidth` is a property of the [element itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/offsetHeight), not its style table.